# Pagination in DynamoDB with Global Secondary Indices

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB schema is:

```
TableName = 'Cities'
PrimaryIndex = '_id'
SecondaryIndex = 'areaId-timestamp-index'
  - areaId is primary key
  - timestamp is sort key
```

The data structure in DynamoDB looks as follows:

```
{ _id: '....', name: 'New York', areaId: 22, timestamp: 1478882557071 },
{ _id: '....', name: 'Washington', areaId: 22, timestamp: 1478882557071 },
{ _id: '....', name: 'Copenhagen', areaId: 18, timestamp: 1478882557071 },
{ _id: '....', name: 'Berlin', areaId: 12, timestamp: 1478882557071 },
```

I want to be able to paginate through the cities under the following conditions:

1. Only cities from, fx, area with id 22
2. Must be paginated in order according to timestamp

My query looks like this:

```
const areaId = 22

const params = {
  TableName: 'Cities',
  Limit: 10,
  IndexName: 'areaId-timestamp-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'areaId = :x',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':x': areaId
  }
}

dynamo.query(params)
```

When I run this I get the expected response with a `lastEvaluatedKey`

```
LastEvaluatedKey = {
    areaId: 22,
    _id: '8c43-d917-f9ec',  // ID of last item in batch
    timestamp: 1478882561962  // Timestamp of last item in batch 
}
```

When I then run the next subsequent query (to get more results), I add the `ExclusiveStartKey` property with the exact same values as returned in `LastEvaluatedKey`.

However, when I run the query, I get:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the LastEvaluatedKey to ExclusiveStartKey, you have to provide entire value you received in whatever format.

```
const areaId = 22
const params = {
  TableName: 'Cities',
  Limit: 10,
  LastEvaluatedKey:response.ExclusiveStartKey, // Get it from previous query respose and use in same format
  IndexName: 'areaId-timestamp-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'areaId = :x',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':x': areaId
  }
}
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks